# Stopping a user from editing system indices

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elk

The below is the code I use to give a certain set of users access to any indices that start with "custom-". But I want the users to be able to do whatever they want to ANY index (so "*"), EXCEPT for the system indices (which start with "."). Is there a way I can do this with the below code, perhaps with a regex? I tried `"names": [ "a-zA-Z0-9" ],"` but that didn't work.

```
curl -XPUT  https://elasticsearch1:9200/_xpack/security/role/custom-users -u elastic -k -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
    "indices": [{
        "names": [ "custom-*" ],
        "privileges": ["all"]
    }],
    "metadata": {
        "version" : 1
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Regular expressions for the index names must be wrapped in `/`. Try something like `"names": [ "/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/" ],"`

Comment: @xeraa I have that in there now, but I can't do basic operations even on the "custom..." index. Must be missing something with that regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
{ "names": ["@&~(^..+)"], "privileges": ["all"] }
```